# returning values from function or method multiple times by only calling the class once

Tags: php, arrays, oop, class, methods

I have a members.php file that shows my websites members. I echo members name by using foreach method. A *method* of **Members class** returns an *array*, then I use **foreach loop** in the *members.php* file to echo the members. I am trying to aovid writing as less php code as possible in my *members.php* file where my html files are located. Is there a way to avoid using **foreach** inside *members.php* file?

For example, is it possible to return value from a *method* couple of times? (by only calling the object once). Just like how we normally call the functions? This question doesn't make sense, but I am just trying to see if there is a away around this issue?

Comment: Is your `members.php` file a *view*? If so, I don't think using a `foreach` in a view is frowned upon. What are your qualms against using a `foreach` ?

Comment: yes it is the file that is viewed by the client(people who visit the site), It makes the code look ugly.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an intermediate function that caches whatever the Members-method returns and return just one index from the cache, specified by a parameter. But then you are back to using a some kind of loop.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with a loop in your view. After all, PHP *is* a templating language.

However, you could write an object method to return/print a formatted members list.